# Need help installing Modoboa Mail Server

Tags: lxc, lxd

this is my first job as IT. I don't have much knowledge about Servers, but I'm trying to learn really hard.

Having said that, please, I really need help trying to deploy a mail server. I have this server, and I've installed Modoboa (modoboa.org) in a LXD container, I've used the installer provided by modoboa and it finished with no problems. The problem is that I don't know how to expose the container over the net, I've read that nginx could help to accept incoming connections to my server for redirecting to my LXD container. But I'm not sure if that is correct, please i would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

P.s: Sorry for the grammar, I'm not native english speaker hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, running a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA, sending emails) and a Mail Delivery Agent (MDA, receiving emails) is a bit of a complex task. It simply is not enough to install a server and connect it to the internet.

It would be helpful to have basic knowledge about things like:

- DNS
- SMTP/IMAP/POP3
- IP/Routing
- Firewalling

For your setup, you need to make sure that

- the mailserver processess mails for your domain
- incoming ports (25 SMTP, 465 SMTPS) to (at lease one) your offical addresses are forwarded to your local mailserver, which should reside in a DMZ
- DNS is set up with A and AAAA records to advertise your maildomain with the official address.

This is sufficient to receive emails, from outside.

Ideally, you should practice internal mailrouting with a lab-setup.

Comment: Thank you!, I'll read about that immediately! I didn't know where to start.

Comment: Correction: you need MX records to advertise your maildomain in DNS. A and AAAA records are for ip4 and ip6 hostnames.